# Books about the measurement for Hamiltonian Energy

Tags: measurement, resource-request, adiabatic-model

I am searching for articles/books about the measurement energy of Hamiltonians in adiabatic quantum computing. Do you know of any good resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find a number of good articles on Hamiltonians in Adiabatic Quantum Computing. Please let me share a few prominent articles here.

- [Hamiltonian engineering for adiabatic quantum computation: Kazutaka Takahashi](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.07177)
- [Adiabatic Quantum Computation with a 1D projector Hamiltonian](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.0385)
- [Non-diagonal problem Hamiltonian for adiabatic quantum computation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329182120_Non-diagonal_problem_Hamiltonian_for_adiabatic_quantum_computation)
- [Realizable Hamiltonians for universal adiabatic quantum computers](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.78.012352)